# Botão de login com facebook nao aparece

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook

Estou tentando chamar o botão do facebook em uma pagina `index.php,` mas o mesmo não aparece na pagina

abaixo o código:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charsert="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
 <title>Home</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" scr="./fbapp/fb.js"></script>
  <div id="content" style="width: 70%, float: left;">
  <h2>Welcome <?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {echo $_SESSION['name']; }?> </h2>
   </div>

   <div id="sidebar" style ="width 20% float: right">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) { } else { ?><div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="plubic_profile, email" onlogin="
    checkLoginState()" ></div><?php } ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

no arquivo `fb.js` e `logincallback`, coloquei minha id do `facebook developers`

abaixo minha estrutura de pastas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o index.php está na pasta mysite

Comment: Você está usando ele localmente, normalmente nada do facebook, nem os botões de like e share, aparecem quando vc está offline. Teste a página já hospedada e online, ele deve aparecer.

Comment: Sabe aquelas APIs legais e fáceis do Google? Pois é, no Face é ao contrário...